# Rails and Postgres: Finding items that are a "good deal"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have two models in my Rails application which keeps track of the prices of products at different shops. Here they are, but simplified:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :name

    def latest_prices
        prices.where('created_at >= ?', 30.days.ago)
    end

    def average_price
        latest_prices.prices.map(&:value).sum / latest_prices.count
    end
end

class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :value, :shop_name, :created_at
    belongs_to :product
end
```

I now want to find all `Price` objects which fall below the current average for that product. That basically means all `Prices` created in the last 30 days, that have a price below the recent average price for that `Product`.

Is this possible? I'm using Postgres.

**Edit:** I should have mentioned - I want to implement this method from the `Price` model - that is, just be able to display all prices that are a good deal, rather than all prices for a Product that are good deals.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [named scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) in ActiveRecord, you can use composition to get what you want:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :name
  has_many :prices
end

class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :value, :shop_name, :created_at
  belongs_to :product

  scope :latest, where('created_at >= ?', 30.days.ago)
  scope :less_than, lambda { |value| where("value < ?", value) }

  def good_deals
    latest.less_than(average('value'))
  end

end
```

Comment: That's almost perfect, but how can I do it from the `Price` side? That is, I don't care which products I show, I just want to show the good deals. How would I do `def good_deals` in the `Price` model?

Comment: I just edited the code, the good_deals method in Price is almost identical to the one in Product, it just doesn't need to refer to the `prices` ActiveRecord::Relation

Comment: That makes perfect sense. And what if I only wanted to get the average value from the last 30 days (ie. how would I change `latest.less_than(average('value'))`)? Sorry to keep asking more things!

Comment: You would remove `less_than`. It would look like `latest.average('value')`. To understand this better, read about named scopes and ActiveRecord relations, they can be chained freely.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :name

  def your_query
    prices.where('created_at >= ?', 30.days.ago).where('value < ?', average_price)
  end

  def latest_prices
    prices.where('created_at >= ?', 30.days.ago)
  end

  def average_price
    latest_prices.prices.map(&:value).sum / latest_prices.count
  end

end
```